# multiple Standardcontroller

Tags: standardcontroller, visualforce, apex

I have to use VF page of a custom object in Account page layouts.Please find my apex class as below.
Apex class:

```
 global with sharing class poistionController {

     public HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c pos{get;set;}

     public poistionController(Apexpages.StandardController Account) {

         pos = [select Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c,Name,Account_OAPI__c,Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c,Id,Territory_OAPI__c,Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c from HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c where HCP_Account_OAPI__c= :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

     }

}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c" extensions="poistionController" showHeader="false">
   <div align="center" width="550px">
      <b>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: NAME{!HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.name}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c{!HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Account_OAPI__c{!HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.Account_OAPI__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c{!HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: id{!HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.id}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Territory_OAPI__c{!HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.Territory_OAPI__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c {!HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c }"/>
       </b>
   </div>
</apex:page>
```

Please let me know the wayout.

Comment: follow the stream and eventually you'll get to the sea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saikat

To any Standard Page layout, You can only add visualforce pages which uses the same objects standard controller.

So in your case you need to make your VF page to use the Account Standard Controller instead of the Custom object standard controller..

and use the variable pos in the apex outputText fields to bind the field values..

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="poistionController" showHeader="false">
   <div align="center" width="550px">
      <b>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: NAME{!pos.name}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c{!pos.Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Account_OAPI__c{!pos.Account_OAPI__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c{!pos.Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: id{!HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c.id}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Territory_OAPI__c{!pos.Territory_OAPI__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="HCP DEPTH TRACKER: Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c {!pos.Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c }"/>
       </b>
   </div>
</apex:page>
```